# While loop condition is not giving anticipated results

Tags: java

i am programming a Fibonacci series, every thing works fine except that i am failing to limit the out put accoring to the while condition (While output < maxOutput) is failing to limit my output to the value entered by a user. Where am i getting my while condition wrong.See my code below

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fibonacci {

    private static int fib(int prev_Total, int current_Num) {
        return  current_Num + prev_Total; // return sum of the two
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int f_Num, s_Num, maxOutput;

        Scanner maxNum = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the first value: ");
        f_Num = maxNum.nextInt(); 
        System.out.println("Enter the second value: ");
        s_Num = maxNum.nextInt(); 
        System.out.println("Enter the maximum value of the series: ");
        maxOutput = maxNum.nextInt(); 

        System.out.println(f_Num);  // print the first value by default 
        System.out.println(s_Num); // print the second value by default

        int prevTotal = f_Num; // initialise prevTotal
        int currentNum = s_Num; // initialise currentTotal
        int output = 0;  // initialise output

        while (output < maxOutput) {

            output = fib(currentNum, prevTotal); // assign the result of first two numbers added together to first output
            prevTotal = currentNum;  // update prevTotal (currentNum becomes our new prevTotal)
            currentNum = output;     // update currentNum (output becomes our new currentNum)
            System.out.println(output); // print output 

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some results ? I will be better to see what's wrong.

Comment: Enter the first value:                                          
8
Enter the second value: 
5
Enter the maximum output of the series: 
100                                                                                                                                                                                                                            Results         
8
5
13
18
31
49
80
129

Comment: You are calculating before printing, and the check only comes afterwards.

Comment: move your sysout statement to top of while loop...

Comment: How must it look like?

Comment: Oh! yeah it works out, thanks a milion times...

Comment: Now another problem, since output is initilised to 0, it prints 0 before the rest of the values.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
while (true) {
    // assign the result of first two numbers added together to first output
    output = fib(currentNum, prevTotal);

    // update prevTotal (currentNum becomes our new prevTotal)
    prevTotal = currentNum;

    currentNum = output;
    if (output > maxOutput) {
        break;
    }
    // print output 
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

...hope I helped you!

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the loop, use a do .. while() it will work.

Edited:

Put the  System.out.println(output); in the first line of the loop, after the while, like:

```
  while (output < maxOutput){
        System.out.println(output); // print output 
      ...
```

Comment: Oups, you're right... Was too fast with my answer. I will edit.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop will should be somewhat like:

```
while (output < maxOutput){
    System.out.println(output); // print output 
    output = fib(currentNum, prevTotal); // assign the result of first two numbers added together to first output
    prevTotal = currentNum;  // update prevTotal (currentNum becomes our new prevTotal)
    currentNum = output;     // update currentNum (output becomes our new currentNum)
}
```

EDIT:
A slight edit in logic will work out

```
int output = 0;
int prevTotal = s_Num; // initialise prevTotal
int currentNum = output = fib(f_Num, prevTotal); // initialise currentTotal with output
while (output < maxOutput){
    System.out.println(output); // print output 
    output = fib(currentNum, prevTotal); // assign the result of first two numbers added together to first output
    prevTotal = currentNum;  // update prevTotal (currentNum becomes our new prevTotal)
    currentNum = output;     // update currentNum (output becomes our new currentNum)
}
```

Comment: Prints extra zero, but otherwise OK.